# Android Device Monitor will not displayed in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

How to recover form this error? I run the emulator and then try to get the Android Device Monitor. But this error corrupts that.

The log file code as follows.
[image]

Comment: How about open the log and show us what's inside (if it is not too big)?

Comment: I have updated the answer with little bit code from log file